# BigInteger is saved as String in spring mongo

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

```
public class Product {
    @Id
    private String productId;
    private BigInteger stock;
}

template.save(product);
```

stock is saved as string in mongo collection eg : {"stock":"20"} , it should be saved as {"stock":20} , how to store this as number ?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: how to store this as number in mongo

Comment: Why `BigInteger` ? why not `Integer` or `Long` ?

Comment: Integer range does not serve the purpose thats why BigInteger is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/6d662461b89589a8485e4ae3ec37e8bd42c5c500/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/convert/MongoConverters.java#L202), that simply is what Spring decides to use as a representation.
The underlying problem is that there is no valid numeric [MongoDB datatype](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/) that can be used to reliably represent all possible values of BigInteger.